# how do I unload & load a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I've got a class in /lib that I'm mucking with and testing via the console. I'm making changes to the class (adding a debugger line for instance) and using `reload!` but the new or removed line is not reflected in the version of the code that the console is running.

Tried these:

- `config.cache_classes = false`
- `reload!`
- `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

  `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/service_processors"]`

  `config.autoload_paths << 'lib'`

I'm running a saved script that creates an instance of the class. I tried just loading the class at the top of my script, but that seemed to cause some unintended consequences.

So, how do I completely unload a class and then reload it? I'm thinking the script will force an unload of the class, then load the class via the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it that is the problem, but in your `application.rb` you need to add the following line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

And secondly, to make sure that classes/modules are found correctly on reload, the naming has to follow Rails conventions. This means that snake-casing a module or class name should give the filename, and different namespaces (or nesting) should be in different folders.

Some examples to make this more clear :)

```
class SomeClass     --> /lib/some_class.rb
class SomeHTTPStuff --> /lib/some_http_stuff.rb
class API::Stuff    --> /lib/api/stuff.rb
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

**Invalid after Rails tag added**

Well, to load a class:

```
load "lib/class.rb"
```

To reload:

```
load "lib/class.rb"
```

Those settings are irrelevant.

Comment: I tried that, but I got some weird behavior. 'Those settings are irrelevant' -- pretty sure they determine what environment gets loaded. Maybe I should have included the Rails tag.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda wasted some of your time.

Comment: @jcollum: Not at all. Sorry I couldn't help.